# python build vs wheel packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging, python-wheel

I am going through python packaging, build and PyPI cycle. My current understanding is that:

- using the [wheel package](https://pypi.org/project/wheel/), we can create a whl package.
- the [build package](https://pypi.org/project/build/) can also create a whl package.

Which module should be used when? What's the difference between the PYPI modules wheel and build?

Comment: `build` is just a build tool for PEP-561-compliant packaging.  It *uses* `wheel` to produce wheels.